# Heroku shows "Build Succeeded" for Python App, but the App does not open open, only showing a Heroku "default page"

Tags: python, heroku

I am new to Heroku. I have built a python app that I deployed on Heroku. The log (reproduced below) does not show any error (Heroku "Overview" page shows "Build Succeeded"). However, when I open the app, a Heroku default page ("Getting Started with Python on Heroku") pops out and my app does not show up. Any idea? Thanks for helping.

[Log shows: https://dynamo-presentation.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your `Procfile`. Also, a bit more information about what your application is supposed to do would add clarity. Please read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

1. The application is very basic: it plots some time series (from a csv file) and png images. It works locally perfectly.

2. The procfile (my understanding is it is not technically required to deploy simple apps) has one line only: web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -

rgds.

Comment: That information should be in your question, not in a comment. Again, please _[edit] your question_ and add it there. Is your `Procfile` in the root of your repository? What do your runtime logs show (try running `heroku logs`)? Is your application meant to be a web application? What files make it up?

Comment: It looks like your application _works_. You just deployed some tutorial code. Did you actually commit your changes, and push that commit?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and your time. I did all all this. I ll find out. Best regards